# Unhandled error. ('The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.')

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am facing this issue for my existing Cordova plugin which is published on https://www.npmjs.com/.

Comment: try to remove android platform and add it again

Comment: Run this first `cordova platform rm android` and then run this command
`cordova platform add android`. Also try to update your node too. I guess you must be using older node version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. I updated the corova version.